# Caching objects and stuff in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I've written my own caching layer for my objects that come out of data access. My reasoning here is I'd like my data access layer to do just that -- data access. I don't really want it to worry about caching, and I'd only like to go in to that layer when I need to fetch data out of the database. Perhaps this is not the right way to think about things -- please let me know if I'm off track.

Anyway, there is at least one issue that I've ran in to so far. In one scenario, I load an object from NHibernate and stick it in the cache in one request. In the next request I get that object from the cache, modify it, and go back down to NHibernate to save it. Obviously NHibernate pukes, in this particular instance with a `"Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"` exception.

So my question is, I guess, is there anything I should be aware of or do to make this work? Or should I just use a 2nd level cache that's built in to NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate has caching for a reason.. use it :)

You'll find there are quite a few options for a second level cache provider that give you much more flexibility for cheaper then you could build it yourself.  A perfect example is something like memcache if you decide you need to run a service on multiple systems.

Comment: Awesome, thanks -- yes, memchached was something I was hoping to support. Now that I think about it, I don't really have any scenarios where I will be caching data that *doesn't* come out of the DB or out of NHibernate so this makes sense.